# UITableView Scroll Bar changes in size as user scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollbar

I have a `UITableView` where the size of each cell is different (it depends on the amount of content needed to be displayed).

As a result (or at least I think as a result), the vertical scroll bar is initially small when the user first starts scrolling. As the user continues to scroll, the scroll bar grows, reaching its correct length when the user makes it to the last cell.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this (I am using Swift and Xcode 7.1.1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That usually happens when the estimated row height you give to the `UITableView` is always larger than the actual row height.

Since you don't say how you're determining the height of your rows, I'm going to assume you're using auto layout.

You either want to set the `estimatedRowHeight` to a value that is closer to the average row height.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

The other option is to use the `UITableViewDelegate` method to return an estimated height for each row that is closer to the actual value.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let estimatedHeight = // some fast calculation based on the data for the row
    return estimatedHeight
}
```

The first option is go for if your rows are generally the same size with little variation. The second option is better if to row size can have a lot of variation or you just have no way of knowing what a good average will be.